# Newly installed packages mucked my display

Tags: apt, gnome, package-management, kde, qt

The following is an extract of my `dpkg` logs:

```
2019-05-12 11:59:54 install libqt5positioning5:amd64 <none> 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2
2019-05-12 11:59:56 install libqt5printsupport5:amd64 <none> 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2
2019-05-12 11:59:57 install libqt5sensors5:amd64 <none> 5.9.5-0ubuntu1
2019-05-12 11:59:57 install libqt5webchannel5:amd64 <none> 5.9.5-0ubuntu1
2019-05-12 11:59:58 install libqt5webkit5:amd64 <none> 5.212.0~alpha2-7ubuntu1
2019-05-12 12:00:01 install google-musicmanager-beta:amd64 <none> 
1.0.467.4929-r 0
2019-05-12 17:10:47 install libid3-3.8.3v5:amd64 <none> 3.8.3-16.2build1
2019-05-12 17:10:48 install libid3tag0:amd64 <none> 0.15.1b-13
2019-05-12 17:10:48 install libopusfile0:amd64 <none> 0.9+20170913-1build1
2019-05-12 17:10:49 install easytag:amd64 <none> 2.4.3-4
2019-05-12 17:10:52 install gnome-icon-theme:all <none> 3.12.0-3
2019-05-12 17:29:23 install libflac++6v5:amd64 <none> 1.3.2-1
2019-05-12 17:29:24 install libid3-3.8.3v5:amd64 <none> 3.8.3-16.2build1
2019-05-12 17:29:26 install kid3-core:amd64 <none> 3.5.1-1
2019-05-12 17:29:27 install kid3-qt:amd64 <none> 3.5.1-1
```

First I installed `google-musicmanager-beta` which appears to have also installed the 5 packages listed above.  Some 5 hours later after downloading my music from google I installed `easytag` which I am assuming caused the packages above that to be installed. I assume also that gnome-icon-theme was installed at the same time.  I did not like `easytag` and I removed it. Nineteen minutes later I installed `kid3-qt` and I assume the the other 3 packages above.

I did what I needed to do with `kid3-qt` i.e edited my music tags.  Once complete I noticed something wrong with my display.  I have low vision and a stable display is very important to me.  The icons on my desktop had suddenly got very large - no problem I just resized the few I have.  The desktop wallpaper looked odd - I can say little more - simply not quite what I was used to.  Opening my Firefox Browser and all my tabs were up the creek - much smaller font and generally I had to resize them using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> but they were still not right.  I used TWEAK UI to change the DPI and font sizes and twiddled more in Firefox but things are still not right - workable but I wish I could get back to how things were.

After some small research I suspect the problem is related to KDE, QT or both - the environment which it would seem `kid3` was written for.

To get back to how things were would it be just the case of removing the packages in reverse order as listed above?

Comment: Before delving too deeply did you try rebooting to see if things reverted to normal?

Comment: Oh yes - should have said. - but things did not revert.